# Change the Color Attribute Links to image/icon in Layered Navigation

Tags: swatches

I am new to Magento I would like to change the color attribute links to an image or icon in the layered navigation as per the pic give below

[image] 
[image]

I need to make it possible through programmatically. Please help in this regard.

Comment: are you creating a module?

Comment: No my requirement is simple. I need to replace the links with images or icons like we do in flags and currency.

Answer (score 1):

pass the label of color to this and it will return you color code. hope this will work for you.

```
public function checkColor($attrColor) {
            $attrColor=str_replace(' ', '', $attrColor);
            $colorArray = array('AliceBlue' => '#F0F8FF',
                'AntiqueWhite' => '#FAEBD7',
                'Aqua' => '#00FFFF',
                'Aquamarine' => '#7FFFD4',
                'Azure' => '#F0FFFF',
                'Beige' => '#F5F5DC',
                'Bisque' => '#FFE4C4',
                'Black' => '#000000',
                'BlanchedAlmond' => '#FFEBCD',
                'Blue' => '#0000FF',

                'YellowGreen' => '#9ACD32');

             $colorArr = unserialize(strtolower(serialize($colorArray)));

            if (array_key_exists(strtolower($attrColor), $colorArr)) {
                $key = $colorArr[strtolower($attrColor)];
            } else {
                $key = "";
            }

            return $key;
        }
```

Comment: Could you please provide which file i need to edit....

Comment: if you want to edit the core file that are not recommended  Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View add function in this class and pass the color label.